# How do i install python3 threading module in linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, python-3.x, python-module

When i try to install to threading module in python3 that error occurs:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement threading (from versions: )
```

No matching distribution found for threading
I have been tried these for installing :

```
pip3 install threading
pip3 install thread
python3 -m pip install threading
python3 -m pip install thread
sudo apt-get install python3-threading
sudo apt-get install python3-thread
```

I've been tried these.And first four occurs that:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement thread (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for thread
```

and last two

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-threading(or thread)
```

what could i do for install that module.

Comment: Where is this requirement file coming from? [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) is part of the standard library, you don't need to install it, just `import threading`.

Comment: But when i try to import thread that appers:                                           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thread'

Comment: Usually that is a sign that you have a file called `threading.py`, so if you do `from threading import thread` it tries to import it from that module.

Comment: that is correct.I've been create that a long time ago.I've been forgotten.I delete that file.After i try to import threading.That worked.there is not exist thread module there is from threading import Thread probably my fault is that.Thanks.

Comment: Yes thread module is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

You can run:

```
pip install thread6
```

pip is a package manager for python and is used for installing python packages or modules. Be aware that you might have python2.x also on your system and pip  v2 might be invoked with this command. To be safe, run:

```
pip3 install thread6
```

Comment: thanks. always a search for the package name when the 'import name' doesn't equal the package name.

Answer (score 1):

If you install thread6 you will be able to import threading

Comment: Anything new from the previews answer?